# Can not add Online accounts in 20.04

Tags: online-accounts

[image]

On Ubuntu 20.04, when attempting to add an online account, I am greeted with:

[image: Ubuntu Online Accounts]

I was able to successfully add the Ubuntu SSO, but unable to add other accounts — the dialogue box goes blank and does not proceed from here.

Comment: Share the picture

Comment: First and foremost, perform `sudo apt upgrade -y` and perform a reboot. I've noted this to be temperamental first boot when outdated.

Comment: You've added a custom theme, and a bunch of GNOME Shell extensions, any of which could cause your problem.

Answer (score 0):

No solution for this anywhere, but you can try WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 gnome-control-center

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Is this a correct answer? If so, can you please explain why this might work so others can learn from your solution. Thanks