# Settings > Online account window is not working

Tags: graphics, settings, online-accounts

When I try to add online accounts from settings, I cannot do it because it opens a blank window. See screenshot.

[image]

I have tried the stuff here: [Can not add Online accounts in 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231190/can-not-add-online-accounts-in-20-04)

I have tried the stuff here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2473841

No effect :(

===================

**Ubuntu details:**

```
(base) pqr@asdf:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

**Hardware details:**

```
(base) pqr@asdf:~$ sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for ak-tippy: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:46 memory:f8000000-f8ffffff memory:a0000000-afffffff memory:b0000000-b1ffffff ioport:d000(size=128) memory:f9000000-f907ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP104 [GeForce GTX 1070]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-graphics
       product: EFI VGA
       physical id: 3
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       capabilities: fb
       configuration: depth=32 resolution=1024,768
```